# Responsive UI below 100px

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

What's the trick behind those websites that even if you open the developer tools and set the width below 100px everything is the same place and nothing is breaking?

Should I create a wrapper for all the components and set a specific width and height?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to bother for such low resolutions, because there isn't any device that will need that. The lowest resolution you should aim for is `320px`.

Read [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/53911/what-is-the-smallest-screen-size-you-design-for) for a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

it s not really a trick, it s just a `min-width` to the container that just prevents the div from shrinking further.